# Easiest way to check which Ethereum network is being accessed?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, nodes, network

Does anyone know of any Web3 queries that can be used to determine whether the underlying node is running for example, Ethereum vs Ethereum Classic?

Would eth_protocolVersion be a suitable query for determining this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask using `eth_getBlockByNumber` for the block `1,920,000` (`0x1D4C00` in hex)

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x1D4C00", true],"id":1}' https://mainnet.infura.io | python -m "json.tool" | grep "\"hash\"" | head -n1
```

It will give you in ethereum `0x4985f5ca3d2afbec36529aa96f74de3cc10a2a4a6c44f2157a57d2c6059a11bb`

In ethereum classic it'll be `0x94365e3a8c0b35089c1d1195081fe7489b528a84b22199c916180db8b28ade7f`

(Source for ETC: http://gastracker.io/block/1920000)